# how to auto-send mails using matlab or gmail?

Tags: matlab, sendmail

I have a matlab code that runs daily, produces some png formatted pics. I want those pics to be sent to my e mail. however matlab's sendmail function requires anti-virus program to be disabled (that i dont want to do).

1-is there a way to make gmail send contents of a specific folder to a specific mail adress regularly?

2- is there a less secure smtp mail server that i can use freely without matlab failing on authorization?

Comment: What OS? I don’t have an answer, but it seems relevant.

Comment: Windows 7.......

Answer (score 1):

> however matlab's sendmail function requires anti-virus program to be disabled

Not necessarily "disabled". You can usually configure your anti-virus or firewall program to allow MATLAB to use SMTP and communicate through related ports.

If you really do not want to deal with SMTP, look into services that allow you to send emails via APIs, e.g. [Amazon Simple Email Service](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) and [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/). Outlook and GMail also provide APIs. However, that would require you to be familiar with HTTP requests and need some additional programming.

Spam emails are a big problem, and anti-virus software and email service providers set up a lot of rules to make sure only the proper emails are sent. It can be hard for you to find a server that allows you to send emails without safety checks. (If there was one, it would probably be exploited and abused, leading to all emails sent from this server recognized as spam in GMail). The easiest thing to do is actually just figure out how to configure anti-virus software and send with SMTP from your own email address.